# upload file for SELENIUM IDE

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

I want to upload a file to automate a process with Selenium IDE from chrome, I already gave the permissions to the extension, however I get the following error yet.

The way I'm loading the file is as follows:

Command: type
id= txtFile
Value: C:\fakepath\factura.xls

**Failed:
Unable to upload files due to cross origin frames in the page**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/LNUqH.png

Answer (score -2):

ist because of the Fakepath

You need to insert the direct path.

You can look it up by making a left click in the Explorer on the document.

The path should be visible now

Comment: I have the same problem even after I changed the fake path with the real path

Comment: this has nothing to do with the filepath, this is a security "feature". i am facing the same problem. the problem is with iframes in html pages. not sure how to workaround that. it might work with selenium-ide-runner when passing the option --disable-web-security